# How do I combine multiple onEdit functions in Google Apps Script?

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am populating part of a google spreadsheet from a google form and manually entering data into several columns on the same spreadsheet.  I have two different onEdit functions that work perfect singularly but only one or the other works when trying to combine them for the same sheet.  These are both pretty simple, one is an auto time stamp based on the value of another cell and the other is to make the spreadsheet font bigger since google forms seems to populate it smaller than I'd like no matter what the sheet settings are.  This is certainly not my specialty so any guidance here is greatly appreciated.  Here is what I have:

```
function onEdit(e) {
 
var row = e.range.getRow();
var col = e.range.getColumn();
 
if(col === 31)
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,30).setValue(new Date());
 
if(col === 34)
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,33).setValue(new Date());
}
```

```
function onEdit1() {
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheets=ss.getSheets();
   for (var i in sheets) {
     sheets[i].getRange(1,1,sheets[i].getMaxRows(),sheets[i].getMaxColumns()).setBackground('#ffffff').setFontSize(14).setFontFamily("Arial").setFontWeight("bold");  }
}
```

Comment: Personally I would not want the second one to run on every edit of every sheet and I'm not sure about the first one.  They're both quite simple but the question is under what conditions do you wish each of them to run.

Comment: @Cooper So when the google form is submitted I would like the font size/style/color to immediately populate the spreadsheet data that way.  The timestamp would only populate one cell based on the value of the cell right next to it, in this case, when any data is entered in any of the cells in columns 31 and 34, then a time stamp is added to the cells in columns 30 and 33 respectively.

Comment: onEdit only fires for user edits.  It won't fire for edit executed by a form submission.  Please explain the time stamp function a little more clearly and put it into your question so others can easily see it.

Comment: @Cooper Ok, so if that's the case is there any other function I can use in Apps Script to change the font style and size other using onEdit?  The timestamp script works fine.  I thought my issue was that I cannot use OnEdit twice in the same script.  If there's another option for permanently changing the font in Sheets so that it is the way I want it coming in from GForms I would love to know it.

Comment: The issue is that every function in a project must have a unique name.

Comment: If you wish to do it on a Google Form Submission then how about using an onFormSubmit trigger for the spreadsheet?

Comment: @Cooper How do I do an OnFormSubmit trigger??

Comment: Look at the triggers menu or go to ScriptApp class

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the timestamp function like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const cols = [31, 34];
  const shts = ['Sheet0', 'Sheet1'];
  if (shts.includes(sh.getName()) && cols.includes(e.range.columnStart)) {
    e.source.toast('Gate1');
    e.range.offset(0, -1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```